# Windows 10 turns itself on, even after successfully being turned off

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Recently there was a major update to Windows 10, and when that update first happened, the issue that I initially ran into was that Windows 10 would refuse to turn off after being shut down.  That's fixed now, by turning off fast startup.  However, now that Windows 10 is successfully turning off, sometimes I will walk back into the room a day or two later or several hours later, and **despite successfully being turned off for some length of time**, Windows 10 will now be turned back on and be sitting at the login screen.

How do you fix it so that it stays off?

Comment: Is the machine a laptop or a desktop/tower?

Comment: @Stese It's a laptop.

Comment: Ok, are you sure it's going off completely? How are you checking this?

Comment: @Stese I'm watching the power button and making sure the light goes off and that the laptop's screen stays black.

Answer (score 2):

Check your bios if it has some advanced Power options or if it has something like PoweOn or Alarm options set.

Also i recomend you to see your power plan options.
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04752217

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps..

I am disabling my wifi connection so that it can not go online. Since then I noticed it did not enable the machine by itself..

Disadvantage is you have to enable Wifi manually when switching on.